# Visual Basic - Display button will not calculate raise percentage

Tags: vb.net

I am trying to get a raise percentage using old salary and new salary in Visual Basics...I am completely stuck. Any ideas where I am going wrong?

```vb
' Name:         Salary Project Project
' Purpose:      Display raise precentage
' Programmer:   <Sarah Jimenez> on <7/24/2014>

Option Explicit On
Option Strict Off
Option Infer Off

Public Class frmMain

    Private Property txtNewSalary As Object

    Private Property txtOldSalary As Object

    Private Sub btnisplay_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btndisplay.Click
        ' display raise precentage

        ' declare named constants and variables
        Dim intOldSalary As Double
        Dim intNewSalary As Double
        Dim intRaisePercentage As Double
        Dim intSalaryDifference As Double

        ' calculates salary difference
        intSalaryDifference = intNewSalary - intOldSalary

        'calculates raise percentage
        intRaisePercentage = intSalaryDifference * intOldSalary

        ' determine raise percentage
        ' message or calculate and display the raise percentage

    End Sub
    Private Sub btnExit_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnExit.Click
        Me.Close()

    End Sub

    Private Sub TextBox3_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles TextBox3.TextChanged
        'displays raise percentage
    End Sub

    Private Sub btnDisplay_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnDisplay.Click
        'Displays the raise percentage
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: a) your variables (like intOldSalary) are never initialized with some starting value presumably from a Text control b) the result never goes anywhere like a new textbox.

Comment: Do you know how to calculate salary raise percentage on paper?

Comment: I suppose that is wrong as well...I have these final projects due Sunday and I have been working on these for days :/ Programming is just so hard on me! So to get the percentage im assuming that you must take the difference of the old and new salary and divide it into the old salary?

Comment: actually (newsalary - oldsalary) * 100 / oldsalary will give the percentage raise

Comment: Is there a reason why you use a double ?

Answer (score 0):

If you need to get the percentage you could do it like this.
Dim OneP As Integer = intOldSalary / 100
intRaisePercentage = intNewSalary / OneP - 100
TextBox3.Text = intRaisePercentage & "%"

I don't know where you get the values from so i just add them in the code.

I also changed the double to Integer

If you use Integer The result will be a round percentage Like 10%
If you want to have a percentage like 11.4% change all the Integers to Double

```
Option Explicit On
Option Strict Off
Option Infer Off

Public Class frmMain

Private Property txtNewSalary As Object = 1100
Private Property txtOldSalary As Object = 1000


Private Sub btnisplay_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btndisplay.Click
    ' display raise precentage

    ' declare named constants and variables
    Dim intOldSalary As Integer = txtOldSalary
    Dim intNewSalary As Integer = txtNewSalary
    Dim intRaisePercentage As Integer
    Dim intSalaryDifference As Integer

    ' calculates salary difference
    intSalaryDifference = intNewSalary - intOldSalary

    'calculates raise percentage

    Dim OneP As Integer = intOldSalary / 100
    intRaisePercentage = intNewSalary / OneP - 100
    TextBox3.Text = intRaisePercentage & "%"
    'intRaisePercentage = intSalaryDifference * intOldSalary

    ' determine raise percentage
    ' message or calculate and d
End Sub
Private Sub btnExit_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnExit.Click
    Me.Close()

End Sub

Private Sub TextBox3_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles TextBox3.TextChanged
    'displays raise percentage
End Sub

Private Sub btnDisplay_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnDisplay.Click
    'Displays the raise percentage

End Sub
End Class
```

Answer (score 0):

In following line your calculation is incorrect

```
' calculates salary difference
intSalaryDifference = intNewSalary - intOldSalary

'Incorrect Calculation
'calculates raise percentage
intRaisePercentage = intSalaryDifference * intOldSalary
```

Correct your calculation like this

```
intRaisePercentage = (intSalaryDifference * 100) / intOldSalary
```

And use `Deciaml` datatype instead of `Double`. Double will not show actual decimal values. Use Double only when you are trying to store very big scientific value. `ie. 1254366.698 x Pi`